# Why is so much software suddenly missing from Ubuntu Software Center in Ubuntu 16.10?

Tags: software-center

After doing a clean install of Ubuntu 16.10, I am noticing a **huge** amount of software previously available in the Ubuntu Software Center is not there anymore. Examples include:

- Code::Blocks
- Eclipse
- Geany

Interestingly, NetBeans, IDLE, and Stani's Python Editor are still present.

How do I get things back to the way they were before I upgraded?

Software Center version number: 3.20.1

Comment: I see the same problem here. there are still available from command line though

Comment: I'm going to use synaptic, but I wonder why this happened in the first place =/

Comment: Same here I just use the command line. This question was asked a few weeks ago but I'm on my phone and don't have the link

Comment: I think part of this is explained by poor search functionality. Search for 'tux' and you won't find SuperTuxKart, but a search for 'super' will. But a lot of packages seem to be flat out missing as searching for the package name doesn't find it. Nor can it be found by manually searching by category.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is because the update has messed up a little bit in your /etc/apt/sources.list, where are located the repos' URLs.

You should see what's checked and unchecked in your "Software and Updates" (type it in the main menu)

Here's a link for more information : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

Hope it helped you :)

Comment: Main, Universe, Restricted, and Multiverse are checked. This is really strange